# Loop through items and sum items in SPSS

Tags: loops, sum, spss

I have two sets of variables called ITEM 1 to ITEM 47, and another called L1 to L47. What I want to do is to calculate the sum of Ls if any ITEM#i=1. What I wrote is as following:

COMPUTE LSUM=0.
 LOOP
       #i=1 to 47.
       IF (ITEM(#i)=1) LSUM=LSUM+L(#i).
 END LOOP.

But I got an error message saying the characters do not match any existing function or vector. What should I do then? Your inputs will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Sincerely,
Lucy

Comment: See the DO REPEAT command. This exact same question was asked recently on the NABBLE list-serve, http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Loop-through-items-and-sum-items-td5715454.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
COMPUTE LSUM=0.
exe.

vector vitems = ITEM 1 to ITEM 47.
vector vl = L1 to L47.

LOOP #vecid = 1 to 47.
do IF (  vitems(#vecid) eq 1 and not missing(vl(#vecid))  ).
compute LSUM=LSUM+vl(#vecid).
end if.
END LOOP.
exe.
```

See the VECTOR command in SPSS. You can not just create loop and treat variables as in array. They must first be put into vectors. Also, check the COMPUTE command. I think SUM would be more appropriate because if you write " compute v1 = v2 + v3 " and v2 has data but v3 is blank, v1 will be blank.